# Разбиение массива

Tags: java

Можем ли из массива вида:
21.10.2018   223344
22.10.2018   234567
23.10.2108   234565
разбить на два массива, отдельно на даты по порядку и отдельно соответствующие числа.

Comment: можно если брать первый столбец и второй отдельно.

Comment: @RomanC а если все данные в одну строку записаны , как бы их отсортировать.

Comment: Никак, если вы не знаете формат данных.

Comment: @RomanC что вы имеете ввиду ,когда говорите о формате данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройдите по массиву циклом и сделайте на его основе два других массива. Если просто разделить строку "пополам" то это примерно так:

```
date[i] = text[i].substring(0, 10);
numb[i] = text[i].substring(11);
```

Строковые даты и числа так же можно распарсить в объекты нужных классов.
Дату в LocalDate, числа в... BigIntger например.